# What should the probability of success be so that 95% of players will win in seven or fewer tries?

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

What should the probability of success be so that 95% of players will win in seven or fewer tries?

My attempt was incomplete and ultimately incorrect:

$$E(X)=0.95= \sum^{7}_{i=1} x \cdot P(X=7) $$
$$=1p+2(1-p)p+3(1-p)^2p+4(1-p)^3p+5(1-p)^4p+6(1-p)^5p+7(1-p)^6p$$

Comment: How many tries are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation can be described by the geometric distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) which can be interpreted as

> The probability distribution of the number X of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set { 1, 2, 3, ... }

Now, if $X\sim Geom(p)$, then $P(X \leq k) = 1 - (1-p)^k$.

Setting $k=7$ and $P(X \leq 7)=0.95$ we have,
$$
0.95 = 1 - ( 1 - p)^7
$$
$$
\implies p  = 1 -.05^{1/7}
$$
$$
\approx 0.3481637
$$